# Angular Typescript interface of number is set in form validation to null , then unary plus operator throws errors if not set

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, unary-operator

While I know that there are several ways of setting up angular typescript interfaces and then interacting with them..  This is my problem.

I set the interface

```
export interface EditUPC {
    weight: number,
    // other fields
}
```

Then in reactive forms in component

```
private initForms(fb: FormBuilder){
   upcForm: fb.group({
     
      weight: null,
      // other fields
   })
}
```

Next with SAVING the form

this line blows up with "Cannot read property of Null" because of the "+" unary operator to convert to number..

```
 this.upcEdit = 
 {
     weight: +this.form.get('upcForm').get('weight').value,
     //other fields
 }
```

So while I could write a function or have conditionals on my several numeric fields , is there an easier/better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert your form to an object with `getRawValue()`.

```
this.upcEdit = upcForm.getRawValue();
```

Comment: well, how would it affect would i want to end up being a number?   so i set the value in the form to null ,  then since its an optional field,  user leaves it empty an with + , that forces it to be a number and then when i do JSON.stringify ...  i for sure am not going to have quotes as it is is a string  -

Comment: Consider modifying your input to type number like this `<input type="number" ...`. Then the default value will be zero.